# alfresco webscript get hostname params

Tags: url, alfresco, parameters, host

I want to know  hotname params in javascript webscript. 
Informations i need are :

1. url protocol (http|https)
2. server port
3. hostname

Is there a way to find these information in a share or alfresco webscript ?

Thank you.

Comment: What language are you writing your webscript in - Java or JavaScript? (The easiest way to get the details differs between the two is all)

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a Java webscript, then your best bet is probably to inject the [SysAdminParams bean](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/admin/SysAdminParams.html) to the webscript as a spring dependency. It is available as a bean with ID `sysAdminParams`

If you're writing a JavaScript webscript running on the Repository (Alfresco), then there's the [ScriptUrl object](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptUrls.html) available as the `urls` base script object, which you can use to fetch the details.

If you're writing something on the Share side, often the simplest option is to call the `org/alfresco/repository/site/site-share-view-url.get` at something like `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/sites/shareUrl?nodeRef={nodeRef}`. The will return you the fully-qualified URL to view that node in Share, saving you the trouble of building it yourself!